# Sendmail relays to 127.0.0.1 instead of MX record

Tags: redhat, sendmail

I am new to sendmail. For some reason the mail are relayed to 127.0.0.1 and its not find the To: domain mx record.

```
Oct  7 00:17:46 e-pubxxx sendmail[1732]: g975HjZY001732:
   to=unix@sysmail.support.net, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:01, 
  xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30549, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], 
  dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (g975Hjs6001737 Message accepted for delivery)
```

The server is running sendmail

```
Version     : 8.11.6   Vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
```

I am also getting an error in /var/log/maillog as below. not sure if this is related to the issue.

```
SYSERR(root): Cannot open btree database /etc/domainaliases.db: Invalid argument
```

My /etc/domainaliases.  (example)

```
truth-andjustice@truthabc.com truthabc
*@bandwindustrialxxxx.com bandwindustrialxxxx.com
```

and i created the hash using cmd:

```
makemap hash /etc/domainaliases.db < /etc/domainaliases.db
```

the permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        45424 Apr 26  2018 /etc/domainaliases
-rw-r-----    1 root     root        94208 Oct  6 23:50 /etc/domainaliases.db
```

Comment: Why not use a sane MTA like postfix - sendmail is stupid hard?  Some wild guesses - did you specify domainaliases.dB rather then domainaliases in config? Did you check /var/log/audit.log in case its an SELinux thing?

Comment: Try sending a mail from the command line, e.g., https://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/, so mail -s "Test Subject" user@example.com < /dev/null, then look at the /var/log/maillog. 

Try running:
makemap btree /etc/domainaliases.db < /etc/domainaliases

Answer (score 1):

Sendmail is no longer by default installed as set root uid.
To preserve traditional functionality sendmail relays messages submitted by local users to local sendmail daemon at 127.0.0.1:25.

---

It seems that your sendmail expects the database to be in `btree` format

```
SYSERR(root): Cannot open btree database /etc/domainaliases.db: Invalid argument
```

**BUT** you have compiled it to `hash` format with wrong input file

```
makemap hash /etc/domainaliases.db < /etc/domainaliases.db
```

Try the following command to compile the database

```
makemap btree /etc/domainaliases < /etc/domainaliases
```

`makemap` adds itself correct database filename extension (`.db`).